# Conditional probability of a Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

The question is as follows:

> Consider a Poisson process $\left \{ N_{t} \right \}_{t\geq 0}$ with $\lambda =3$ events per hour. What is the probability that $2$ events occur in the first hour and $2$ events occur in the second hour, given that $4$ events occur in the first $2$ hours?

Since this deals with a conditional, I think that we can just view these as uniform and use a binomial distribution. Thus the probability becomes
$$\binom{4}{2}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^2\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^2=\frac{3}{8}.$$
However, I am not $\textit{too}$ sure about this.  I thought the probability was 
$$\mathbb{P}(N_{1}=2,N_{2}=4 \mid N_{2}=4),$$
but I didn't really know how to go from here.  It has been a while since I've dealt with the stuff.  Can anyone provide me some feedback?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right.

Verification:\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(N_{1}=2,N_{2}=4 \mid N_{2}=4) &= \mathbb{P}(N_{1}=2,N_{2}-N_1=2 \mid N_{2}=4)\\
&= \frac{\left(\exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda^2}{2!}\right)^2}{\exp(-2\lambda)\frac{(2\lambda)^4}{4!}}\\
&= \frac{\frac14}{\frac{2^4}{4!}}\\
&= \frac{3!}{16}\\
&= \frac{3}{8}\end{align}